# Скрытие ключа для расшифровки алгоритма

Tags: c++

Собственно говоря, как скрыть ключ от глаз реверсера?

Хранить прямо в коде его, думаю, небезопасно.

Заксорить думаю, что тоже не пойдет. Реверсер подберет значение рано или поздно от `1` до `255` в таком вот коде

```
byte const xoredString[6] = {0xDE, 0xA4, 0xDD, 0xAA, 0xDC, 0xB6};
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
myString+= (char)(xoredString[i] ^ 0xEF);
}
```

Какие есть предложения?

Comment: Никак. Например, любой эмулятор развернёт ваши код и данные до состояния исполняемого/читаемых. И даже не будет заморачиваться самим ключом, он просто дождётся нужного момента, когда ваш расшифровщик сам сделает всю работу :)

Comment: Всё, что бежит на машине пользователя, находится под полным его контролем. Вы можете лишь _затруднить_ анализ вашего кода, но спрятать ключ надёжно вы не сможете. Единственный надёжный выход — пусть ваш код бежит на _сервере_.

Comment: @VladD интересно как это происходит в случае с C++?

Comment: @MatthewHaig: Что именно? Вынос кода на сервер? Вам придётся научиться писать web-приложения. А какая ваша задача верхнего уровня?

Comment: @MatthewHaig, поясните вопрос. На вашем сервере нельзя исполнять программы, которые написаны на C++? Тогда это какой-то экзотический сервер :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Никак нельзя.  Лучше не хранить в коде. Предлагаю хранить в сервере, и через прокси скачивать ключ.
2. Хранить с настройках (в конфигурационнах файлах) ключ для расшифровки слабого шифра ключа. То есть. Главный ключ шифруется ключем который находится в конф файле. тогда можно под каждого пользователя создавать отделные ключи для расшифровки основного ключа
3. Использовать внешний канал для передачи ключа. К примеру СМС или емайл. Вы в коде храните основной ключ в шифровенном виде. а открыть его можно только используя конфигурации устройства, которые передаются Вас через другой канал. но конечно не открытом виде. И Вы генерируете обратный ключ для расшифровки основного ключа.

4*. Сделайте макрос, который создает проверку почти везде в вашем коде. Что бы почти для каждой функции будет проверка ключа. И так как этих ключей будет очень много, это затруднит обходит проверки.

5. Используйте не основной ключ а ключ сгенерированный для каждого клинета отдельно. и расшифровку делаете по 3ми ключами

А(Б(С(текст))) = Текст

в программе все данные в виде С(текст)

устройства генериреут ключ Б. Клиент передает ключ по любому каналу (хоть СМС)

Вы из Б генерируете ключ А . И передаете обратно.

В этом случае сервер не нужен